# How to understand dreams?

Tags: dream

What shall we do if we get a bad dream?  
Are there any hymns to be recited to get rid of ill effect of a bad dream? 
What shall we do if we get a good dream?  
What are good signs & bad signs(objects/creatures/incidents) that appear in dreams as future predections?  
What type of dreams will become true and how soon? 
Where is the reference of dreams and its effects in any scriptures?

Comment: Are there any hymns to be recited to get rid of ill effect of a bad dream?  ==> Do Hanuman Chalisa.

Comment: This much questions! :O ?

Comment: These are too many questions... please avoid asking multiple questions henceforth, that's why I've closed your question as of now

Comment: This is a good question , it should have status open.

Comment: If you get a bad dream, get up, go to the bathroom, wash your feet, do achamana/have a glass of water, chant hanuman chalisa and go back to sleep.If you get a good dream, get up and dont go back to sleep.If you see Siva or Vishnu, chant purusha sUkta. Dreams that occur in the early hrs of the morning are said to come true.Good signs/bad signs are usually given in panchaangaas.There is a swapna sastra that talks about all this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your experiences in your daily life becomes your dreams,your meetings,your doings,your thoughts,your anger,your wishes,youe failures,your success,your relations all of them together form your dreams.You can never know the beginning of a dream.
From [psychology.about.com](http://psychology.about.com/od/statesofconsciousness/p/dream-theories.htm):

> Dreams have fascinated philosophers for thousands of years, but only recently have dreams been subjected to empirical research and concentrated scientific study. Chances are that you’ve often found yourself puzzling over the mysterious content of a dream, or perhaps you’ve wondered why you dream at all.
>
> First, let’s start by answering a basic question –
>
> **What is a dream?**
>
> A dream can include any of the images, thoughts and emotions that are experienced during sleep. Dreams can be extraordinarily vivid or very vague; filled with joyful emotions or frightening imagery; focused and understandable or unclear and confusing.
>
> **So why do we dream? What purpose do dreams serve?**
>
> While many theories have been proposed, no single consensus has emerged. Considering the enormous amount of time we spend in a dreaming state, the fact that researchers do not yet understand the purpose of dreams may seem baffling. However, it is important to consider that science is still unraveling the exact purpose and function of sleep itself.
>
> Some researchers suggest that dreams serve no real purpose, while others believe that dreaming is essential to mental, emotional and physical well-being.

---

> Yet in Hinduism,they consider things seen in  dreams as significant:

From [Hinduism.about.com](http://hinduism.about.com/od/relatedfields/a/dreamsymbols_3.htm):

> **Lamp:** Very favourable dream. Very happy life. Family peaceful. This dream is always of good signs.
>
> **Learning:** You will attain influence and respect. Good omen to dream that you are learning and acquiring knowledge.
>
> **Leprosy:** To dream that you have leprosy always indicates a very great future misfortune. Perhaps you have committed some crime to be severely punished by law. You will have many enemies.
>
> **Light:** To dream of lights is very good. It denotes riches and honour.
>
> **Limbs:** Breakage of limbs indicates breakage of a marriage vow.
>
> **Lion:** This dream indicates greatness, elevation and honour. You will become very important among men. You will become very powerful and happy.
>
> **Money:** Receiving money in dream denotes earthly prosperity. Giving of it denotes ability to give money.
>
> **Mother:** If you dream that you see your mother and converse with her, it indicates that you will have prosperity in life. To dream that you have lost your mother indicates her sickness.
>
> **Murder:** To dream that you have murdered somebody denotes that you are going to become very bad and wretched, vicious and criminal.
>
> **Nectar:** To drink nectar in dream indicates riches and prosperity. You will be beyond your expectations. You will marry a handsome person in high life and live in great state.
>
> **Nightmare:** You are guided by foolish persons. Beware of such people.
>
> **Noises:** To dream of hearing noises indicates quarrels in family and much misery in life.
>
> **Ocean:** The state of life will be as the ocean is perceived to be in dream, viz., calm and peaceful life when the ocean is calm and troublesome life when the ocean is stormy, etc.
>
> **Office:** If you dream that you are turned out of the office it means that you will die or lose all property. This is a very bad dream for all people.
>
> **Owl:** Denotes sickness and poverty, disgrace and sorrow. After dreaming of an owl, one need not have any hope of prosperity in life.
>
> **Palace:** To live in a palace is a good omen. You will be elevated to a state of wealth and dignity.
>
> **Paradise:** This is a very good dream. Hope of immortality and entrance into Paradise. Cessation of sorrows. Happy and healthy life.
>
> **Pigs:** This indicates a mixture of good and bad luck. You will have great troubles but you will succeed. Many enemies are there, but there are some who will help you.
>
> **Prison:** This is a dream of contrary. Indicates freedom and happiness.
>
> **Rain:** This foretells trouble especially when it is heavy and boisterous. Gentle rain is a good dream indicating happy and calm life.
>
> **River:** Rapid and flowing muddy river indicates great troubles and difficulties. But a river with calm glassy surface foretells happiness and love.
>
> **Ship:** If you have a ship of your own sailing on the sea, it indicates advancement in riches. A ship that is tossed in the ocean and about to sink indicates disaster in life.
>
> **Singing:** This is a dream of contrary. It indicates weeping and grief. Much suffering.
>
> **Snakes:** You have sly and dangerous enemies who will injure your character and state of life.
>
> **Thunder:** Great danger in life. Faithful friends will desert you. Thunder from a distance indicates that you will overcome troubles.
>
> **Volcano:** Quarrels and disagreements in life.
>
> **Water:** This indicates birth (of some person).
>
> **Wedding:** This indicates that there is a funeral to be witnessed by you. To dream that you are married indicates that you will never marry. Marriage of sick persons indicates their death.
>
> **Young:** To dream of young persons indicates enjoyment. If you are young, it indicates your sickness. You may die quickly.
>
> **Earthquake:** This foretells that great trouble is going to come, loss in business, bereavement and separation. Family ties are broken by death—quarrels in family and fear everywhere, heart breaking agony and disaster from all sides.
>
> **Eclipse:** Hopes are eclipsed. Death is near. Enjoyment may be put an end to. There is no use of dotting on the wife, for life is coming to an end. The friend is a traitor. All expectations will bear no fruit.
>
> **Elephant:** Good health, success, strength, prosperity, intelligence.
>
> **Embroidery:** Those persons who love you are not true to their salt. They will deceive you.
>
> **Famine:** National prosperity and individual comfort. Much enjoyment. A dream of contrary.
>
> **Father:** Father loves you. If the father is dead, it shows a sign of affliction.
>
> **Fields:** Very great prosperity. To walk in green fields shows great happiness and wealth. Everything happens good. Scorched fields denote poverty.
>
> **Fighting:** Quarrels in families. Misunderstanding among lovers, if not temporary separation. A bad dream for merchants, soldiers and sailors.
>
> **Fire:** Health and great happiness, kind relations and warm friends.
>
> **Floods:** Successful trade, safe voyage for traders. But to ordinary persons it indicates bad health and unfavourable circumstances.
>
> **Flowers:** Gathering beautiful flowers is an indication of prosperity. You will be very fortunate in all your undertakings.
>
> **Frogs:** These creatures are not harmful. This dream therefore is not unfavourable. It denotes success.
>
> **Ghost:** This is a very bad omen. Difficulties will be overwhelming. Terrible enemies will overpower you.
>
> **Giant:** Great difficulty to be encountered. But meet it with boldness. Then it will vanish. This indicates that you will have an enemy of the most dreadful character.
>
> **Girl (unmarried):** Success, auspiciousness will come over you. Hopes will be fulfilled.
>
> **God:** This is a rare dream which few people experience. Great success and elevation.
>
> **Grave:** Some friend or relative will die. Recovery from illness doubtful.
>
> **Hanging:** If you are hung, it is good to you. You will rise in society, and become wealthy.
>
> **Heaven:** The remainder of your life will be spiritually happy, and your death will be peaceful.
>
> **Hell:** There will be bodily suffering and also mental agony. Great suffering due to enemies and death of relatives, etc.
>
> **Home:** To dream of home-life in early boyhood indicates good health and prosperity. Good sign of progress.
>
> **Husband:** Your wish will not be granted. If you fall in love with another woman’s husband, it indicates that you are growing vicious.
>
> **Ill:** To dream that you are ill shows that you will have to fall a victim to some temptation, which, if you do not resist, will injure your character.
>
> **Injury:** If you are injured by somebody else, it means that there are enemies to destroy you. Beware of them. Change of locality is desirable.
>
> **Itch:** This is an unlucky dream. Denotes much difficulty and trouble. You will be unhappy.
>
> **Jail:** If you dream that you are in jail it indicates that in life you will prosper. This is a dream of contrary.
>
> **Journey:** This indicates that there will be a great change in conditions and circumstances. Good journey indicates good conditions and bad journey with troubles indicates a bad life.
>
> **King:** To appear before a friendly king is a sign of great success, and before a cruel king is very unfavourable.
>
> **Lamp:** Very favourable dream. Very happy life. Family peaceful. This dream is always of good signs.
>
> **Learning:** You will attain influence and respect. Good omen to dream that you are learning and acquiring knowledge.
>
> **Leprosy:** To dream that you have leprosy always indicates a very great future misfortune. Perhaps you have committed some crime to be severely punished by law. You will have many enemies.
>
> **Light:** To dream of lights is very good. It denotes riches and honour.
>
> **Limbs:** Breakage of limbs indicates breakage of a marriage vow.
>
> **Lion:** This dream indicates greatness, elevation and honour. You will become very important among men. You will become very powerful and happy.
>
> **Money:** Receiving money in dream denotes earthly prosperity. Giving of it denotes ability to give money.
>
> **Mother:** If you dream that you see your mother and converse with her, it indicates that you will have prosperity in life. To dream that you have lost your mother indicates her sickness.
>
> **Murder:** To dream that you have murdered somebody denotes that you are going to become very bad and wretched, vicious and criminal.
>
> **Nectar:** To drink nectar in dream indicates riches and prosperity. You will be beyond your expectations. You will marry a handsome person in high life and live in great state.
>
> **Nightmare:** You are guided by foolish persons. Beware of such people.
>
> **Noises:** To dream of hearing noises indicates quarrels in family and much misery in life.
>
> **Ocean:** The state of life will be as the ocean is perceived to be in dream, viz., calm and peaceful life when the ocean is calm and troublesome life when the ocean is stormy, etc.
>
> **Office:** If you dream that you are turned out of the office it means that you will die or lose all property. This is a very bad dream for all people.
>
> **Owl:** Denotes sickness and poverty, disgrace and sorrow. After dreaming of an owl, one need not have any hope of prosperity in life.
>
> **Palace:** To live in a palace is a good omen. You will be elevated to a state of wealth and dignity.
>
> **Paradise:** This is a very good dream. Hope of immortality and entrance into Paradise. Cessation of sorrows. Happy and healthy life.
>
> **Pigs:** This indicates a mixture of good and bad luck. You will have great troubles but you will succeed. Many enemies are there, but there are some who will help you.
>
> **Prison:** This is a dream of contrary. Indicates freedom and happiness.
>
> **Rain:** This foretells trouble especially when it is heavy and boisterous. Gentle rain is a good dream indicating happy and calm life.
>
> **River:** Rapid and flowing muddy river indicates great troubles and difficulties. But a river with calm glassy surface foretells happiness and love.
>
> **Ship:** If you have a ship of your own sailing on the sea, it indicates advancement in riches. A ship that is tossed in the ocean and about to sink indicates disaster in life.
>
> **Singing:** This is a dream of contrary. It indicates weeping and grief. Much suffering.
>
> **Snakes:** You have sly and dangerous enemies who will injure your character and state of life.
>
> **Thunder:** Great danger in life. Faithful friends will desert you. Thunder from a distance indicates that you will overcome troubles.
>
> **Volcano:** Quarrels and disagreements in life.
>
> **Water:** This indicates birth (of some person).
>
> **Wedding:** This indicates that there is a funeral to be witnessed by you. To dream that you are married indicates that you will never marry. Marriage of sick persons indicates their death.
>
> **Young:** To dream of young persons indicates enjoyment. If you are young, it indicates your sickness. You may die quickly.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Hinduism.SE. Did you wrote this all on your own or are you citing this from some random website?

Comment: Some mine words and some reffered from resources....some which I know....some for the answer and clarification sake of the OP

Comment: Ok ok great, so I would like to say that if you copy from any website, make sure you provide a link from where you copied, i.e in a way we credit the site by providing links so please do the needful..

Comment: You say dreams relate with the future? Is it related to karma?

Comment: @JavaTechnical What I think is, dreams are related to the past rather than future,because they are the blur images of our  past(which may even include some future plannings)...there is no logical relation between karma and dreams...................................The conflict to these thoughts only arises, when we consider the stories of gods. In which gods used to prophicize the future incidents by showing themselves up in dreams

Comment: @keshavsrinivasan the answer was edited because it had repetitive lines, but not sure why you reverted it. Do cross check the answer again.